# Arrange multiple REST API Swagger specifications

Tags: rest, swagger, specifications, swagger-ui

We use Swagger-based REST API specification for different projects. So each project has its own Swagger UI with a description of endpoints. All these UIs are deployed on different servers, under different domain names, which is not cool at all from the organisation perspective.

Are there any nice options to store multiple Swagger specifications in a single place? It could be any service for a REST API descriptions management, which consumes the Swagger Specification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found some nice options for a REST API specifications management:

- **Apiary** (apiary.io)
- **Restlet** (restlet.com)
- **SwaggerHub** (swaggerhub.com)

All the three services support the [OpenAPI Specification](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification), which is based on the Swagger 2.0 spec.

**Apiary** has a good collaboration management and supports a REST API validation.
However, it is pretty expensive. A suitable plan costs 99$ per month: apiary.io/pricing

**Restlet** also has a possibility for a collaborative work and it supports a functional testing.
Comparing to Apiary, Restlet has a better choice of pricing options: restlet.com/pricing

**SwaggerHub** is the most optimal choice in my case. It is designed especially for multiple Swagger specifications management. The service has a support of all the code generators developed for Swagger. Nevertheless, it does not provide REST API testing/validations tools unlike Apiary and Restlet.
The biggest advantage of SwaggerHub is pricing. A ratio of specifications number per $ is the best with a maximum number of 25 collaborators on each API: swaggerhub.com/prices